# What is the another way to write methods instead of streamapi

Tags: java

For example : Method addBook(Book book) – adds book to the collection;
Method countAvailableBooks() – counts and returns all available books;
Method getBookWithMostPages() – finds and returns title of the book with most pages;
Method countUniqueAuthors() – counts and returns how many authors there are in the collection;
Method getAuthorsByCountry(country) – counts and returns how many authors from the given country there are in the collection;
Method sortByTitle() – orders the collection by book title;
Method sortByAuthorsFirstName() – orders the collection by author’s first name;

How can i write these methods without using streamApi?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Library {

    private String name;

    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public Library(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        if (book == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        books.add(book);
    }

    public long countAvailableBooks() {
        return books.stream()
                .filter(Book::isAvailable)
                .count();
    }

    public String getBookWithMostPages() {
        if (books.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return books.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getPages))
                .get()
                .getTitle();
    }

    public int countUniqueAuthors() {
        return books.stream()
                .map(Book::getAuthor)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .size();
    }

    public int getAuthorsByCountry(String country) {
        return books.stream()
                .map(Book::getAuthor)
                .filter(author -> author.getCountry().equals(country))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .size();
    }

    public List<String> sortByTitle() {
        books.sort(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle));
        return books.stream()
                .map(Book::getTitle)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<String> sortByAuthorsFirstName() {
        books.sort(Comparator.comparing(book -> {
             return book.getAuthor().getFirstName();
        }));
        return books.stream()
                .map(Book::getTitle)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Library{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", books=" + books +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s wrong with using the stream API? What’s the motivation to change your implementation?

Comment: @Bohemian im new in the programming and it'll be an exam for me without stream API

Comment: @Bohemian Probably the same, why i needed to rewrite some Code Last Year in my Java-Lecture at my University: Some People are Stuck at Java6/7 times and dont know anything after that. (My Lecturer couldnt read Streams for example and even try-with-resources were new to him)

Comment: @KeremDeniz Try to Write what each Method does in Pseudo-Code. From that, u can easily implement a stream-less implementation. But that requires, that u understand, what the Stream-Code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loops

```
public void addBook(Book book) {
    if (book == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    books.add(book);
}

public long countAvailableBooks() {
    long availableBooksCounter = 0;

    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book.isAvailable()) {
            availableBooksCounter++;
        }
    }

    return availableBooksCounter;
}

public String getBookWithMostPages() {
    if (books.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Book theBiggestBook = null;

    for (Book book : books) {
        if (theBiggestBook == null || book.getPages() > theBiggestBook.getPages()) {
            theBiggestBook = book;
        }
    }

    return theBiggestBook.getTitle();
}

public int countUniqueAuthors() {
    Set<Author> uniqueAuthors = new HashSet<>();

    for (Book book : books) {
        uniqueAuthors.add(book.getAuthor());
    }

    return uniqueAuthors.size();
}

public int getAuthorsByCountry(String country) {
    Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book.getAuthor().getCountry().equals(country)) {
            authors.add(book.getAuthor());
        }
    }

    return authors.size();
}

public List<String> sortByTitle() {
    List<String> sortedTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    books.sort(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle));

    for (Book book : books) {
        sortedTitles.add(book.getTitle());
    }

    return sortedTitles;
}

public List<String> sortByAuthorsFirstName() {
    List<String> sortedTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    books.sort(Comparator.comparing(book -> book.getAuthor().getFirstName()));

    for (Book book : books) {
        sortedTitles.add(book.getTitle());
    }

    return sortedTitles;
}
```

Comment: For the sorting I would first add the items to the new list and then use `Collections.sort` so the original list is not changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I replaced streams with loops, because according to the OP requirements there shouldn't be streams